# C++ overloading generic function with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I am trying to write a simple serialization protocol. The `send` for a container type should call `send` on each of the elements (which may themselves be container types).

However I can't figure out how to do this. I have written three functions that each work individually, but I can't figure out how to have C++ select and dispatch the proper function. How do I do this?

As it stands right now, clang says I can't redefine `send` with the same signature (not even in order to to SFINAE).

I am using C++17, but I cannot use an external library such as boost. [edit] This is for a personal challenge. I want to know how to do this with vanilla C++. After all, that library had to be written in vanilla C++ by somebody, right? [/edit]

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class pair_t>
std::void_t<typename pair_t::first_type, typename pair_t::second_type>
send(pair_t pair) {
    using first_t = typename pair_t::first_type;
    using second_t = typename pair_t::second_type;

    send<first_t>(std::get<0>(pair));
    send<second_t>(std::get<1>(pair));
}

template <typename list_t>
std::void_t<typename list_t::value_type, typename list_t::size_type>
send(list_t list) {
    using value_t = typename list_t::value_type;

    for (const value_t& elem : list) {
        send<value_t>(elem);
    }
}

template <typename int_t>
void
send(typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<int_t>::value, int_t>::type val) {
    std::cout << "Sending integral val: " << val << std::endl;
}

int obj0 = 1;
std::vector<int> obj1;
std::pair<int, int> obj2;
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> obj3;
int main() {
    // send<int>(obj0);
    // send(obj1);
    // send(obj2);
    // send(obj3);
}
```

Comment: *Why* can't you use an external library?  Is this homework? a job-interview task? a work project with political restrictions?

Comment: A personal challenge. I want to know how to do this with vanilla C++. After all, that library had to be written by somebody, right?

Comment: You should [edit] that explanation into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template specialization:

```
template <typename T> void send(const T&);

namespace detail {
  template <typename T> struct Send;  // primary template

  template <typename T> struct Send<std::vector<T>> {  // specialization for vector
    static void send(const std::vector<T>& v) {
      for (const auto e : v) ::send(e);
    }
  };

  template <typename T, typename U> struct Send<std::pair<T, U>> {  // for pair
    static void send(const std::pair<T, U>& p) {
      ::send(p.first); ::send(p.second);
    }
  };

  template <> struct Send<int> {  // for int
    static void send(int i) { std::cout << i; }
  };
}

template <typename T> void send(const T& arg) { detail::Send<T>::send(arg); }

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  std::vector<int> vi = { 1, 2, 3 };
  std::pair<int, int> pi = { 4, 5 };
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vpi = { { 7, 8 }, { 9, 0 } };
  send(i);
  send(vi);
  send(pi);
  send(vpi);
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cQNpsgSFYmiurqRT

Note that this solution requires specializations for all types of containers you want to support (which is different from that *use this implementation for any type that has nested `value_type` and `size_type`*).

---

Or, you can go with SFINAE as well:

```
template <typename T> struct is_vector : std::false_type { };
template <typename T> struct is_vector<std::vector<T>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T> struct is_pair : std::false_type { };
template <typename T, typename U> struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T> void send(T i, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0) {
  std::cout << i;
}

template <typename T> void send(const T& p, std::enable_if_t<is_pair<T>::value, int> = 0) {
  send(p.first); send(p.second);
}

template <typename T> void send(const T& v, std::enable_if_t<is_vector<T>::value, int> = 0) {
  for (const auto & e : v) send(e);
}

... // same main
```

---

Alternatively, you can also check for existence of member types as follows:

```
template <typename T> struct has_value_type {
  using yes = char[1]; using no = char[2];
  template <typename C> static constexpr yes& test(typename C::value_type*);
  template <typename> static constexpr no& test(...);
  static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};   

... // similarly: has_size_type, has_first_type, and has_second_type

template <typename T> void send(T i, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0) {
  std::cout << i;
}

template <typename T> void send(const T& p, std::enable_if_t<has_first_type<T>::value && has_second_type<T>::value, int> = 0) {
  send(p.first); send(p.second);
}

template <typename T> void send(const T& v, std::enable_if_t<has_value_type<T>::value && has_size_type<T>::value, int> = 0) {
  for (const auto & e : v) send(e);
}

... // same main
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/qD7vp2ebzFaR15qf

Comment: The last solution doesn't work for a pair of vectors. https://wandbox.org/permlink/bipJY3cdB4isLrZE

Comment: @charmoniumQ It does not, but it's only caused by the order of definitions. If you simply separate declarations and definitions, then the order does not matter: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8LUGCwPwQAWvJulQ

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that as far as the compiler is concerned, your declarations for pair and list both look like:

```
template <typename T>
blah send(T arg) {
    ...
}
```

... and there is no use of `enable_if` in that signature.  I think you need to put `enable_if` into the argument type.  (I would also take `list_t` by const reference - you don't want to be copying a list around unnecessarily).

Comment: I thought that expanding `std::void_t<typename list_t::value_type, typename list_t::size_type>` would fail if `list_t::value_type` or `list_t::size_type` does not exist. How do I check for these?

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to solve this is tag dispatching.

First write traits for your properties.

```
template<class T, class=void>
struct is_pair; // inherits from true_type or false_type depending on if T is a pair.
template<class T, class=void>
struct is_list;
```

now we dispatch.

```
namespace impl {
  template <class pair_t>
  void send(pair_t pair, std::true_type /* is pair */, std::false_type, std::false_type) {
    using first_t = typename pair_t::first_type;
    using second_t = typename pair_t::second_type;

    send<first_t>(std::get<0>(pair));
    send<second_t>(std::get<1>(pair));
  }

  template <typename list_t>
  void send(list_t list, std::false_type, std::true_type /* list */, std::false_type) {
    using value_t = typename list_t::value_type;

    for (const value_t& elem : list) {
      send<value_t>(elem);
    }
  }

  template <typename int_t>
  void send(int_t, std::false_type, std::false_type, std::true_type /* is integral */) {
    std::cout << "Sending integral val: " << val << std::endl;
  }
}
template<class T>
auto send( T t )
-> decltype( impl::send( std::move(t), is_pair<T>{}, is_list<T>{}, std::is_integral<T>{} ) )
{ impl::send( std::move(t), is_pair<T>{}, is_list<T>{}, std::is_integral<T>{} ); }
```

Comment: I couldn't get [this to work.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zk5eRiMJd8LEObk5) [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1DizACXxdyEOcOGm) is my attempt.

Comment: @charmoniumQ forward declare the `send2` templates, then implement `send`, then implement `send2`.  Then `(void)pi;` because you forgot to use it. ;)